# Dynamically create template-based table cells based on data

Tags: html, dynamic

How does one dynamically create table cells based on a dataset?  Is Javascript/ajax required for this?  Is it possible to use a template div for the cells?

Just looking for some direction.

Comment: you can check this out: https://pugjs.org

Comment: and yes, you would probably need Ajax to retrieve the data from the server in some way so the webpage could compile the template and inject the compiles HTML into the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamically create table cells, you need to manipulate the DOM, so you need Javascript.

An example, which will add a new row to a table:

```
var table = document.getElementById('[tablebodyelement]'),
    row = document.createElement('tr'),
    data = ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"];

for(var i=0; i<row.length; i++){
  var cell = document.createElement('td');
  td.appendChild(document.createTextnode(row[i]));
  row.appendChild(td);
}

table.appendChild(row);
```